# Specializing template for pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, template-specialization

I want to specialice a template class to make it behave differently for pointers of type Base and all other pointer types. I tried it using enable if. But it's not working the way i want it. Can anyone tell me what to do about it. 
the code that i tried:

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived:public Base
{
};

class Non_base
{
};

template<class T,class Enable=void> class Vector
{
public:
    Vector()
    {
        cout<<"Constructor of Vector "<<endl;
    }
};



template<class T> class Vector<T*>
{
public:
    Vector()
    {
        cout<<"Constructor of Vector<T *> "<<endl;
    }
};



template<> class Vector<Base*>
{
public:
    Vector()
    {
        cout<<"Constructor of Vector<Base*> fully specialized"<<endl;
    }
};


//template<class T> class Vector<T *>:public Vector<Base *>
//{
//public:
//    Vector()
//    {
//        cout<<"Constructor of Vector<Base*> partially specilized"<<endl;
//    }
//};


template<class T> class Vector<T*,typename enable_if<is_base_of<Base,T>::value>::type>
{
    Vector()
    {
        cout<<"Constructor of Vector<Base*> partially specilized"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add `enable_if` to a subset of an existing overload set, you usually need to add it to the remaining members as well. When some overloads are enabled, the others must be disabled, or there will be ambiguity.

```
template<class T> class Vector<T*,typename enable_if<!is_base_of<Base,T>::value>::type>
{
public:
    Vector()
    {
        cout<<"Constructor of Vector<T *> "<<endl;
    }
};
```

You don't need to add `enable_if<!…>` to the full specialization as it's already the best match of the set so there cannot be ambiguity.

Comment: When I tried to do the same thing for a template function I am getting an error : redeclaration of template  class, which seems right.  I declared a function for taking pointers and in one i checked whether it's of type Base and in the other i checked whther it's not  of base type. But both the function where having same argument.How to avoid it?

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you're describing. Maybe open another question.